# How are floating point numbers formatted when working with the floating point stack/co-processor?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86

I'm working on a project for school, and part of the project is to read in integers and floating point numbers (in the format (-)9.999E+/-99) from a file, parse them so they're stored in the correct format instead of just as ASCII characters, and then perform certain operations on them. I've gotten the integers working, but I'm not sure where to start with the floating point numbers.

Part of the project description says that the floating point numbers MUST be converted to single precision IEEE floating point representation. I'm wondering about whether or not I need to do extra work to get them in this format.

For example, say I load an integer to the stack and find the reciprocal:

```
fild qword [num]  
fld1  
fdivr
```

How is the number currently on top of the stack formatted? Is the value in the single precision IEEE format? Or are floating points represented in some other way?
Basically it's a matter of whether I can just read in each digit in the string one by one, do some scaling by the number after the 'E' and add it together, or if I have to do some bit string operations to find the sign bit, biased exponent, and significand, then somehow concatenate them all together.

Also, I'm not allowed to use C functions, so fscanf isn't an option.

Thanks in advance, I'm grateful for any help you guys can give me!

Comment: only a very simple experiment is required to figure this out.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Internally, the CPU keeps values on the FP stack in 80-bit extended format but it can store (and load) values as single or double precision floats (among others).